# PysimpleGUI Tkinter - Sg.Output Doesn't work with HTML Test runner

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Hi I am trying to add console output to a window created using PySimpleGui , It works Perfectly until I add html test-runner , can anyone suggest a method to use both of them at once

```
import unittest
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Sampletestclass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1_State(self):
        self.assertTrue(2 > 9)
        print('1')

    def test_2_State(self):
        print("2")

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
layout = [[sg.Button('Start Test')], [sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-OUTPUT-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

i = 0
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Start Test':
        i += 1
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(f'Test {i}\n\n')
        unittest.main(exit=False) ==>Works
```

if I change to

```
    unitest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(Title="Title"))
```

it doesn't

```
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set option `stream` to `sg.Output.Widget`, and again, set option `exit=False` of `unittest.main`

```py
import HtmlTestRunner
import unittest
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Sampletestclass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1_State(self):
        self.assertTrue(2 > 9)
        print('1')

    def test_2_State(self):
        print("2")

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
layout = [[sg.Button('Start Test')], [sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-OUTPUT-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

i = 0
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Start Test':
        i += 1
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(f'Test {i}\n\n')
        unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=window['-OUTPUT-'].Widget), exit=False)

window.close()
```